# How can I keep framerate high when animating lots of pencil-tool-drawn graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a game and I have a bunch of animating movie clips moving at the same time. Normally my games just have simple shapes, but this time I'm upping the production value by going inside each movieclip and using the pencil tool to draw a nice image with shading, etc. It's a lot of lines.

The problem is that when I go to animate these, then the framerate drops to about 2 fps. I have about 10-20 objects animating at the same time.

Things I've tried:
- Using Flash's Optimize feature (No change)
- Exporting the line drawings as a png and then reimporting (Helped some, but quality went down, and it still was only about 10fps)

What can I do to have great looking flash art and animations but still keep framerate high? I know there must be a standard workflow here that I'm missing.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried bitmap caching ?

Comment: Read up on that, looks like I'd just need to set CacheAsBitmap to true. I can try and see if that works.

Comment: If the vectors are dense, cacheAsBitmap should make a big difference but only if your objects remain static inside their container. The fps when using pngs is weird though, it seems to me that animating 20 bitmaps shouldn't be a problem at all. You got any intensive calculations running in the background?

Comment: Ok, tried cacheAsBitmap, and it helped, but it didn't solve the problem. It took it from about 2 fps to 4 fps, which is a big improvement, but is still nowhere near the 20-30 I'm aiming for. No huge calculations going on, just about 10-20 movie clips motion tweening down about 100px over 20 frames.

Comment: According to the optimization tool, my drawings have about 10,000 curves... is that just way way way too many? Maybe I'm thinking about the pencil tool all wrong and need to really cut down on my lines.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I was one of the two developers of Scarygirl.

Our Bitmap Cached Animations are pretty good when you're on a PC, especially with a lot of memory. We cached all our character animation except for Scarygirl herself, as she had way too many animations and it was possible for her to change size.

On mobile devices, using animation caching in this way is not optimal as switching bitmaps is slow, writing bitmaps is slow, and they have less memory than most PCs. Starling is good here as it is written to use the hardware in an optimized way.

The problem with Starling (and similar) comes in both tooling and detail. You either have to do spritemap blitting where you export each frame beforehand (bloat in size, larger toolchain etc) or do animations that are tweened only, which there are not such great tools for.

We also have a new test which also integrate SpriteSheets. This seems slower for PCs at least, especially when not using Canvas3D!

http://blog.touchmypixel.com/2008/11/caching-animation-frames-vs-spritesheets/

Answer (score 1):

Make use of 2D hardware acceleration thanks to Flash 11's new Stage3D api's. If you wanna keep things as close to the normal classes as possible *(Sprite, DisplayObject etc)* without fussing over the low level AGAL needed and shaders etc then I'd recommend Starling. It is a fantastic framework that let's you use the amazing speed benefits of hardware acceleration without having to learn anything you don't already know.

For more information, check out http://gamua.com/starling/. This is your fastest option for what you're trying to achieve, I recommend you try their demo just to see how well it can actually perform.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using blitting with tilesheets as a non hardware accelerated way of boosting your frame rate with animating objects. I am pretty sure cacheAsBitmap has to redraw on each keyFrame.

So, for your animations, you need to create a tilesheet which consists of each frame of your animations laid out on a rectangular bitmap (you can compute this at runtime if you want).

Then at rendering time, you lookup the pixel position of the frame you want from the tilesheet and then draw this area  onto your rendering bitmap via the copyPixel function. The rendering bitmap is then what you use to display your graphics.

I believe the award winning Flash game [ScaryGirl](http://www.scarygirl.com/) used this technique for rendering. You can find out more on the developers blog

http://blog.touchmypixel.com/2008/04/as3-bitmap-cached-animations/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the number of lines and curves makes a huge difference in the framerate. If you are using the pencil tool as a kind of sketching tool, then you'll end up with thousands of curves. Using the pen tool is much better and the low number of lines keeps the framerate high.

Good learning lesson for me. Thanks to everyone for their help!